# php mysql queries returning errors

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone spot the errors in these lines?

```
$string .= "insert into oc_product (model, upc, location, quantity, stock_status_id, manufacturer_id, shipping, price, points, tax_class_id, date_available, weight, weight_class_id, length, width, height, length_class_id, subtract, minimum, sort_order, status, viewed, date_added, date_modified) values ('$name','$upc','',1000,6,0,1,$price,    0,0,'2014-11-16',9.0,11,45,45,45,45,1,1,1,1,0,'2014-11-16 02:23:37','2014-11-16 02:23:37');";
            
$string .= "insert into oc_product_to_category (product_id, category_id) select (select product_id from oc_product where model='$name' and price=$price limit 1), (select category_id from oc_category_description where name='$cats[$i]');";
            
$string .= "insert into oc_product_description (product_id,language_id,name,description,tag,meta_title,meta_description,meta_keyword) (select product_id from oc_product where model='$name' and price=$price limit 1),1,'$name','&lt;p&gt;$desc&lt;/p&gt;','$cats[$i]','$name','$desc','$desc';";
            
$string .= "insert into oc_product_reward (product_id,customer_group_id,points) (select product_id from oc_product where model='$name' and price=$price limit 1),1,0);";
            
$string .= "insert into oc_product_to_store (product_id,store_id) (select product_id from oc_product where model='$name' and price=$price limit 1),0;";
```

These are my errors:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1,'Schar Gluten & Wheat Free Classic White Bread, 14.1 oz (Pack ','
>
> <b>S'
>
> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1,0)'
>
> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0'

The output of `$string` is below

> insert into oc_product (model, upc, location, quantity, stock_status_id, manufacturer_id, shipping, price, points, tax_class_id, date_available, weight, weight_class_id, length, width, height, length_class_id, subtract, minimum, sort_order, status, viewed, date_added, date_modified) values ('Schar Gluten & Wheat Free Classic White Bread, 14.1 oz (Pack ','030684927201','',1000,6,0,1,36.26,    0,0,'2014-11-16',9.0,11,45,45,45,45,1,1,1,1,0,'2014-11-16 02:23:37','2014-11-16 02:23:37');
>
> insert into oc_product_to_category (product_id, category_id) select (select product_id from oc_product where model='Schar Gluten & Wheat Free Classic White Bread, 14.1 oz (Pack ' and price=36.26 limit 1), (select category_id from oc_category_description where name='Bakery & Bread');
>
> insert into oc_product_description (product_id,language_id,name,description,tag,meta_title,meta_description,meta_keyword) (select product_id from oc_product where model='Schar Gluten & Wheat Free Classic White Bread, 14.1 oz (Pack ' and price=36.26 limit 1),1,'Schar Gluten & Wheat Free Classic White Bread, 14.1 oz (Pack ','
>
> <b>Schar Gluten & Wheat Free Classic White Bread:</b><ul><li>Low fat and saturated fat</li><li>Gluten free</li><li>Wheat free</li><li>No lactose</li></ul>
>
> ','Bakery & Bread','Schar Gluten & Wheat Free Classic White Bread, 14.1 oz (Pack ','<b>Schar Gluten & Wheat Free Classic White Bread:</b><ul><li>Low fat and saturated fat</li><li>Gluten free</li><li>Wheat free</li><li>No lactose</li></ul>','<b>Schar Gluten & Wheat Free Classic White Bread:</b><ul><li>Low fat and saturated fat</li><li>Gluten free</li><li>Wheat free</li><li>No lactose</li></ul>';
>
> insert into oc_product_reward (product_id,customer_group_id,points) (select product_id from oc_product where model='Schar Gluten & Wheat Free Classic White Bread, 14.1 oz (Pack ' and price=36.26 limit 1),1,0;
>
> insert into oc_product_to_store (product_id,store_id) (select product_id from oc_product where model='Schar Gluten & Wheat Free Classic White Bread, 14.1 oz (Pack ' and price=36.26 limit 1),0;

Comment: please give us the output of `$string`. (`echo $string;`)

Comment: why tagged SQL SERVER ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the third, fourth, and fifth line are the problem

```
$string .= "insert into oc_product_description (product_id,language_id,name,description,tag,meta_title,meta_description,meta_keyword) (select product_id from oc_product where model='$name' and price=$price limit 1),1,'$name','&lt;p&gt;$desc&lt;/p&gt;','$cats[$i]','$name','$desc','$desc';";

$string .= "insert into oc_product_reward (product_id,customer_group_id,points) (select product_id from oc_product where model='$name' and price=$price limit 1),1,0);";

$string .= "insert into oc_product_to_store (product_id,store_id) (select product_id from oc_product where model='$name' and price=$price limit 1),0;";
```

The above queries have this pattern

```
INSERT INTO tablename (...) (SELECT ... FROM ...),x,y,...
```

which is invalid for insert syntax. Change your queries to this pattern

```
INSERT INTO tablename (...) SELECT ...,x,y,... FROM ....
```

as follows

```
$string .= "insert into oc_product_description
            (product_id,
             language_id,
             name,
             description,
             tag,
             meta_title,
             meta_description,
             meta_keyword) 
            select 
               product_id,
               1,
               '".$name."',
               '&lt;p&gt;$desc&lt;/p&gt;',
               '".$cats[$i]."',
               '".$name."',
               '".$desc."',
               '".$desc."' 
            from oc_product 
            where model = '".$name."' and price = ".$price." limit 1;";

$string .= "insert into oc_product_reward 
            (product_id,
             customer_group_id,
             points) 
            select 
                product_id,
                1,
                0 
            from oc_product 
            where model = '".$name."' and price = ".$price." limit 1;";

$string .= "insert into oc_product_to_store 
            (product_id,
             store_id) 
            select 
                product_id, 
                0 
            from oc_product 
            where model = '".$name."' and price = ".$price." limit 1;";
```

Comment: Just a small input, you should escape your variables. `$string = "foo ". $var . " bar";`

Answer (score 1):

> $string .= "insert into oc_product_reward
>   (product_id,customer_group_id,points) (select product_id from
>   oc_product where model='$name' and price=$price limit 1),1,0);";

There is one closing bracket to much.

Comment: I removed the extra bracket but I'm still getting the same errors

Comment: remove ; before "..i hope it will help you

Comment: @Voltron I recommend you to test every line of your statements alone.
It is hard to figure out the problem in such a huge query.
Then post the line, where the error occurs again.